# Lucene Custom Analyzer - TokenStream Contract Violation

Tags: lucene

I was trying to create my own custom analyzer and tokenizer classes in Lucene. I followed mostly the instructions here:

http://www.citrine.io/blog/2015/2/14/building-a-custom-analyzer-in-lucene

And I updated as needed (in Lucene's newer versions the Reader is stored in "input")

However I get an exception:

> TokenStream contract violation: reset()/close() call missing, reset() called multiple times, or subclass does not call super.reset(). Please see Javadocs of TokenStream class for more information about the correct consuming workflow.

What could be the reason for this? I gather calling reset\close is not my job at all, but should be done by the analyzer.

Here's my custom analyzer class:

```
public class MyAnalyzer extends Analyzer {

protected  TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String FieldName){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new TokenStreamComponents(new MyTokenizer());
}
}
```

And my custom tokenizer class:

```
public class MyTokenizer extends Tokenizer {

protected CharTermAttribute charTermAttribute =
        addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

    public MyTokenizer() {
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        int numChars;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            while ((numChars =
                this.input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                stringBuilder.append(buffer, 0, numChars);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        String StringToTokenize = stringBuilder.toString();
        Terms=Tokenize(StringToTokenize);       
    }

    public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {

        if(CurrentTerm>=Terms.length)
            return false;
        this.charTermAttribute.setEmpty();
        this.charTermAttribute.append(Terms[CurrentTerm]);
        CurrentTerm++;
        return true;
    }

    static String[] Tokenize(String StringToTokenize){

        //Here I process the string and create an array of terms.
        //I tested this method and it works ok
        //In case it's relevant, I parse the string into terms in the //constructor. Then in IncrementToken I simply iterate over the Terms array and //submit them each at a time.
        return Processed;                   
    }

    public void reset() throws IOException {
        super.reset();
        Terms=null;
        CurrentTerm=0;      
    };

    String[] Terms;
    int CurrentTerm;
}
```

When I traced the Exception, I saw that the problem was with input.read - it seems that there is nothing inside input (or rather there is a ILLEGAL_STATE_READER in it) I don't understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading from the input stream in your Tokenizer constructor, *before* it is reset.

The problem here, I think, is that you are handling the input as a String, instead of as a Stream.  The intent is for you to efficiently read from the stream in the `incrementToken` method, rather than to load the whole stream into a String and pre-process a big ol' list of tokens at the beginning.

It is possible to go this route, though.  Just move all the logic currently in the constructor into your `reset` method instead (after the `super.reset()` call).

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked. I've been trying to solve it for the last two days. The reason even seems obvious now.

If I may ask, why is it so bad to process the whole content and then just iterate over it? I did it because most of the tokenizing logic fits into java useful tools e.g. replace and regexes.

Comment: @miv - Just because it's inefficient, both in terms of being slower, and using a lot more memory.

Comment: @femtoRgon - I have similar code and I am upgrading Lucene from 3.5.0 to 8.4.1. I made the required code changes and getting exact same error. I moved all the logic currently in the constructor into your reset method. I don't get any error but it seems the code in reset method is never called. I checked this by debugging the code. If I explicitly call the reset(), I get the error. Does reset() method is called implicitly? Why it is not getting called in my case? Any suggestions please?